# Get object property name self reference

Tags: javascript, reflection

I am looking for a way to get the name of an object property like this:

```
let o = {
 first: 1,
 second: 2
};

function q(prop) {
 // return name of prop
}

console.log(q(o.first));
// should return "first"
```

I am not even sure this is possible, but I am just asking.

The main use case for this is given by dynamic specification of requested attributes while keeping the advantages of using intellisense which can be quite significant for large projects and refactoring purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not even sure this is possible...

Good instinct! It isn't. When you do:

```
q(o.first);
```

the **value** of the `o.first` property (`1`) is passed into `q`. Nothing about the object or its property is passed to `q`, just the value `1`.

If you know what object the value came from, and if that object had only one property with a matching value, you could figure it out. But of course, one or both of those won't be true the vast majority of the time. In the general case, no, there's nothing to tell you that it came from `o.first`.

Answer (score 0):

You try this with slight modification of your code

```
function q(obj,prop)  { 
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    return prop; 
   else
    return null; 
}
```

console.log(q(o,o.first));
Hope this help.

Comment: That doesn't work though, as the actual name would have to be passed to the function `q` as in `q(o, "first")` which defeats the purpose

Comment: yes it's my mistake i passing its value not property name